# Push notification from java/spring server to iOS, Android and web browser clients

Tags: java, android, ios, spring, push-notification

We have an application (java/spring/GWT) on Tomcat that requires push notification to all of the iOS, Android and web browser clients.

I would like to know some information about suitable frameworks for this issue.

Also i want to know, if the spring-websocket maybe a correct selection.

Please note that we want to cover all of three types of platforms (iOS, Android and Web browsers)

If it's possible, please let us know the advantages and disadvantages of your suggestions.

Thanks in advance

Comment: @ Alen, You can use Firebase Cloud Messaging.

Comment: Spring websocket can be a correct selection. Another approach is to use server sent events.